# Can the old Firefox recommended extensions question be viewed by anybody in any way?

Tags: discussion

There was a question that I and many found useful though unfortunately it seems maybe it was deemed subjective and deleted. I had thought it'd be preserved in the database, but not being aware of all the recent deletions, I didn't know it'd be deleted or looks like it has been deleted.

I'd like to save the information from it. I found it more useful than the one time hilarious question about the A and B drives are that now dominates when sorting by vote.

There was an extension somewhere to view deleted threads. But I don't even know the link to that question. Can anybody help with that?

Comment: 10Kers and ♦ mods can see deleted posts on Super User.

Comment: Although it's hard for > 10k users to even find questions once they're deleted, unless you have the link or [a list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73455/popular-deleted-questions-list). Google Cache can be helpful if you want to find recently deleted content.

Comment: That is a horrible elitist philosophy. One has to be brilliant enough to reach 10k+. Sorry, we're not all that brilliant.

Comment: But what would be the sense of deleted questions if everybody could see them? 10k users are given those privileges in order to help maintain the site.

Comment: how does an old deleted question help them maintain the site?

Comment: "But what would be the sense of deleted questions if everybody could see them? "  Well it doesn't make sense it'd be a contradiction, just as a deleted question that some can see and some can't, is a contradiction. It makes as much sense as anybody being able to see it. It's "deleted" not deleted. Some sense could be that it being "deleted" prevents clutter. But if somebody wants to see it then it's not clutter.

Comment: @barlop it's not so much brilliance as simple dedication and persistence to reach 10k

Comment: @Jeff Atwood ruling out the how long it takes aspect, ability plays very little role!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing [this is the link you're asking for](https://superuser.com/questions/587/must-have-firefox-addons). There is a [copy of it on Archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20100106023017/https://superuser.com/questions/587/must-have-firefox-addons), if you really need to get the info from it.

Questions are deleted after a time when they are off topic or otherwise harmful to the site. List questions such as this one are considered non-constructive, so it was removed. The primary reason why 10k users are permitted to see deleted posts is so that they can vote to undelete them, and as an extra privilege. They do not see deleted questions in their normal everyday operation of the site - only when they specifically try to view a question they already have a link for. This is done to maintain the quality of the site. Just because somboedy wants to see it doesn't mean it should be here - people also wanted to see shopping recommendations, but for good reasons, those aren't allowed either.

Comment: Well, I hope in time another place is set up for such questions so they don't harm the site and those that want to see them can benefit, without them getting in the way of other people.

Comment: That place exists in /reddit @bar

Comment: Or Yahoo Answers. @random